# Url Encoding in php

Tags: php, urlencode

I am scrapping some product having special characters such as ®

```
Cool Clarity!® Facial Care Line
```

when ever i am posting this name on Facebook then it displays �

® (registered trade mark sign) converted into �

please help me on this

Comment: Just a note; but you do not seem to have actually asked a question and if we run with this as a question, why are you doing so on a product you are scrapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[utf8_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)** to encode the string.